# JSON string more than one chapter to javascript object

Tags: javascript, html

i am working with JSON in javascript and i want to convert the JSON file to object in javascript. i know that i must use JSON.parse() method. but when i want to see the result i face with the error.
This is my JSON:

```
['{"fname":"amir","lname":"mehrizi","age":"1989-02-05","country":"The US","email":"test@gmail.com"},{"fname":"hamid","lname":"hamidi","age":"1986-03-25","country":"Canada","email":"amir.mehrizi25@gmail.com"},{"fname":"Mickey","lname":"jhmh","age":"1996-02-05","country":"Italy","email":"amir@mehrizi"}']
```

and this is my error :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse ()

thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no single quotes inside the array.The JSON should look a lot like this after removing the illegal characters:

```
[
   {
      "fname":"amir",
      "lname":"mehrizi",
      "age":"1989-02-05",
      "country":"The US",
      "email":"test@gmail.com"
   },
   {
      "fname":"hamid",
      "lname":"hamidi",
      "age":"1986-03-25",
      "country":"Canada",
      "email":"amir.mehrizi25@gmail.com"
   },
   {
      "fname":"Mickey",
      "lname":"jhmh",
      "age":"1996-02-05",
      "country":"Italy",
      "email":"amir@mehrizi"
   }
]
```

This worked out for me in the end:

```js
var json = [{"fname":"amir","lname":"mehrizi","age":"1989-02-05","country":"The US","email":"test@gmail.com"},{"fname":"hamid","lname":"hamidi","age":"1986-03-25","country":"Canada","email":"amir.mehrizi25@gmail.com"},{"fname":"Mickey","lname":"jhmh","age":"1996-02-05","country":"Italy","email":"amir@mehrizi"}]
    
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)));
document.write(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)));
```

I get 3 items in my console.

Answer (score 0):

`Input` is an `array` and not a `String`, hence, `JSON.parse` will not work. The first item in the `array` is a `string`. You need to parse that. However, as it is a collection of objects without a containing parent i.e. `invalid JSON`, you will need to convert it into a `valid json` by surrounding it by square brackets and then parse it.

```js
var arr = ['{"fname":"amir","lname":"mehrizi","age":"1989-02-05","country":"The US","email":"test@gmail.com"},{"fname":"hamid","lname":"hamidi","age":"1986-03-25","country":"Canada","email":"amir.mehrizi25@gmail.com"},{"fname":"Mickey","lname":"jhmh","age":"1996-02-05","country":"Italy","email":"amir@mehrizi"}'];

arr = JSON.parse("["+arr[0]+"]");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i use JSON.stringify() to make this JSON file. i do not think that the type of the file is wrong.also when i use just one curly bracket i can see the result correctly. but when i add other curly brackets like my example, i face with that error.

Comment: of course i do that but unfortunately i do not get the result yet. i am searching about it